# Which algorithm to use for text recognition?

Tags: machine-learning

I am using Naive Bayes to implement a text recognition algorithm.
I had a sizable training set in my database and the algorithm is almost finished.
But there is one problem, during the testing, the time to classify a text into a class from only 2 classes take almost 5 seconds. It will take more than a minute if i have like 60 classes.
I guess the speed is right because i throw every word in the text to my algorithm and compute.
But...
I am wondering beside Naive Bayes, is there any faster algorithm that i can use? Any suggestion?

Comment: Algorithm's complexity depends on number of classes, yes, that's right, but the difference between two and 60 is not this big. Are you using hash table or something else while learning? What's the size of training data? Which language your code written and what's the specs of your pc?

Comment: Naive Bayes is one of the fastest classification algorithms. Normally you need only multiply elements of observation's feature vector with elements of class likelihood feature vector, so time to compute probability for each class depends linearly on the length of feature vectors. Thus, unless you have a billion features (which is very unlikely for OCR), most probably something is wrong with your implementation. Also note that for character recognition NB is not the best possible approach, normally ANNs give better result.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably not the algorithm but your implementation. Use a profiler to find where the time is spent to fix the performance bottleneck or reuse an existing text classification library (for instance nltk in python or opennlp in java).